# Remove underline from TextInputEditText

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I have an android screen which takes email from the user. Below is the snippet of the code, I want to remove the underline which appears below the text.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/email"
    android:textColorHint="@color/blueBackground"
    app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/input_background"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="20dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="20dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="20dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="20dp"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:endIconTint="@color/blueBackground"
    app:hintTextColor="@color/blueBackground">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/blueBackground"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I have tried `android:background="@null"` and

`<item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/transparent</item>`

But it is not working.

[image: EditText]

Comment: Also, you can try ```app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"```.

Comment: In my case was enough to add `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## 2022 Update

My answer has been marked as the solution for the described issue, but it looks like it's got outdated and there's been a better approach around. See [Gunavant Patel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62611522/11342519) for an up to date fix.

---

---

## Original answer

It looks like the Material Components library draws its own underline using `app:boxStrokeColor`. This attribute is a [`ColorStateList`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource#item-element), so you have to create a color state list resource in which all states' colors are set to transparent. So basically you want to create a new file `res/color/filename.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:color="@android:color/transparent"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_checkable="true"
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true" />
</selector>
```

and set the `app:boxStrokeColor` attribute to `@color/filename`.

However, this left me with a black underline which still doesn't respond to `android:background=@null` or `<item name="colorControl*">@android:color/transparent</item>`.

---

### **TL;DR**

Quickfix: if you set the `TextInputLayout` outlined using `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"`, the box looks almost the same, but the underline is gone. In order to remove the stroke just set the `app:boxStrokeColor` attribute to `@null`.

Answer (score 100):

If you want to use the filled box then below code perfectly work for me.

```
app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
```

add above lines in the input layout.

Answer (score 25):

`app:boxBackgroundMode="none"` in parent `TextInputLayout`

Comment: Correct answer I also achieved by this

Comment: It removes the baseline but adds an extra top padding

Answer (score 19):

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.TextInputLayout</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyApp.TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidthFocused">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 11):

Please set boxBackgroundMode in TextInputLayout. This is the simple and proper way to remove underline in TextInputLayout

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:boxBackgroundMode="none" >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/inputEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Working solution

Answer (score 9):

Setting the background of the TextInputLayout to a drawable and the one of the TextInputEditText to transparent removes the underline:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_drawable"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:endIconTint="@color/black"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/black">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

blue_drawable.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="20dp"/>
<solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/></shape>
```

[image]

Comment: Setting `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` to `TextInputEditText` removes the blue background from the  `TextInputLayout` and is therefore not solving my issue

Comment: I fixed this by adding a drawable as a background of the TextInputLayout

Answer (score 9):

You just need write **app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"** and **app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"**
attributes for **TextInputLayout** component.

should be write like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
    app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
    android:hint="@string/email"
    android:textColorHint="@color/blueBackground"
    app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/input_background"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="20dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="20dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="20dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="20dp"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:endIconTint="@color/blueBackground"
    app:hintTextColor="@color/blueBackground">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/blueBackground"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 8):

> If you want app:boxBackgroundMode with filled and without underline than this will work

```
<item name="boxStrokeWidthFocused">0dp</item>
<item name="boxStrokeWidth">0dp</item>
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding this line on `TextInputLayout` works for me:

```
app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
```

**UPDATE**

Inside color res directory add et_box_color.xml file and add below lines inside of it:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:color="@color/transparent"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_checkable="true"
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"/>
</selector>
```

Now add Your Material Edit text like below:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/et_box_color"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/llBank">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/etAmount"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Amount"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I added a background to make a border of the TextInputLayout, remove background of TextInputLayout if you don't need. Background of TextInputEditText will be necessary to make background transparent.

Answer (score 6):

The solution is very simple, you have to add this line to `TextInputLayout` :
`style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"`
and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Easy way;

```
app:boxBackgroundMode="filled"
app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a selector at ***res/drawable***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="0.01" android:color="?attr/background" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="0.01" android:color="?attr/background" android:state_hovered="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="0.01" android:color="?attr/background" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:alpha="0.01" android:color="?attr/background"/>
</selector>
```

**background** here - any color that is close to you background.

**Way 1**
Then set it to your `TextInputLayout`:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
...
  app:boxStrokeColor="@drawable/text_input_selector"
...
```

**Way 2**, trough styles:

***styles.xml***:

```
<style name="vm_textFilledBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@drawable/text_input_selector</item>
</style>
```

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
...
    style="@style/vm_textFilledBox"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your custom TextInputLayout like this

```
package com.google.android.material.textfield

import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
class TextInputLayoutWithoutUnderline @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : TextInputLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    override fun updateEditTextBackground() {
        // XXX don't call super on purpose
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This answer about removing the underline while typing in `TextInputEditText`**

After searching 6 hours about how to remove the underline from `TextInputEditText`, I found a single line solution, its just put          `android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"` inside your `TextInputEditText`.

Now i am not getting any underline while typing in `TextInputEditText`

Comment: Didn't help in my case.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting background to `@null` or `@android:color/transparent`

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I have tried it but it didn't work