# Remove bottom line from TextInputEditText

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

I need to remove the bottom line of `TextInputEditText` I set background to transparent and null but nothing is working.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_textinput_layout"
    android:hint="@string/app_name">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The bg_textinput_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<solid android:color="@color/white"/>

<stroke android:width="@dimen/spacing_1"
    android:color="@color/hint_text_color"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: You don't need this bg_textinput_layout background. Just use boxBackgroundColor to have a white box.

Comment: I applied this style Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox to textinputlayout and now it is working

Comment: Here is the simple solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063519/remove-underline-from-textinputedittext/63308187#63308187

Answer (score 69):

You can apply **`app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"`** and       **`app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"`** (or the`app:boxStrokeColor` attribute using a selector with the same values of the `boxBackgroundColor`).

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
       app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
       app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
       ...>
```

[image: enter code here]

For a white box without background and border:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
    app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
    app:boxStrokeColor="#FFF"
    app:boxBackgroundColor="#FFF"
    ...>
```

[image]

Comment: Why we can not hide the bottom line with FilledBox?

Answer (score 2):

in the TextInputLayout, set app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
in the TextInputEditText, set app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
. it worked for me when my background is white.